# Replace text with another text in a clob field

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Getting error when executing the script. I am try to replace oracle to_date text with sql server convert(datetime_
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '02'.
Msg 132, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
The label 'HH24' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Msg 132, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
The label 'MI' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Looked in google for solutions on how replace works, could not find a solution on how to handle the labels, but i don't think it is lable. I am just replacing one text for another. Looks like sql server does not like oracle time definition.

```
update table
set table.clobfield = REPLACE(table.clobfield,'BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/01/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('02/10/2011 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')',
'BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/01/2011 00:00:00') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'02/10/2011 23:59:59')')
```

I expect sql sever text to replace the oracle to_date text

Comment: Your syntax is all over the place here. You have string literals everywhere and still using some Oracle functions like TO_DATE. Are you storing where clauses in your database?

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing it in Oracle DB then you must be using `Alternative quoting mechanism` to form the string which contains special string characters(In your case quote(')).

You just need to form the string using q'##'. So that whatever written in your string will be considered as it is.

Try the following:

```
update table
set table.clobfield = 
REPLACE(table.clobfield,
q'#BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/01/2011 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('02/10/2011 23:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')#',
q'#BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '02/01/2011 00:00:00') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'02/10/2011 23:59:59')#')
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This update statement is being used in sqlserver.  So i did not uses the alternative.  However, every time I work with the developer, he gets 7 rows updated, but nothing is actually updated the last query tried is   update favorite
 set favorite.transaction_request = REPLACE(favorite.transaction_request,
'TO_DATE(''02/01/2011 23:59:59'',''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'')',' ''02/01/2011 23:59:59'' ')
where favorite_id = 'CSAT SQL REPORT Updated' and user_code in ('8CRAIMACM','CLAHOG','DEESIS','MARWOZ','MEGMAG','PATNITEST','ZOWMAR2') .  It is a clob field beng updated.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just needed to escape the quotes.

Here is what it should look like:

```
   update table set table.clobfield = REPLACE(table.clobfield,'BETWEEN TO_DATE(''02/01/2011 00:00:00'', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') AND TO_DATE(''02/10/2011 23:59:59'', ''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'')',
'BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, ''02/01/2011 00:00:00'') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,''02/10/2011 23:59:59'')')
```

You must just ensure that the times will match exactly otherwise it will not replace the values.